# Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and have a database of users. I'm trying it such that a user can click on a button of their favorite shoes and it updates the database. My schema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    }, 
});

// methods ======================
// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Posting DB function:

```
exports.addToFavs = function(req, res) {
    var size_result = req.query.size;
    var brandToFind = req.query.brandToFind;
    req.db.users.update({email: req.user.email}, {$set: favoriteShoes[{name: brandToFind, size: size_result}]}); /*, function(error, favoriteShoes) {
        if (error) return next(error); 
        if (!favoriteShoe) return next(new Error('Failed to save')); */
        console.info('Added %s with id=%s', brandToFind, size_result);
        res.redirect('/favorites');
    //})
};
```

HTML Button:

```
<form action="/result" method="post">
            <center><button>Save to Favorites</button></center>
          </form>
```

Appropriate Routes:

```
app.post('/result', searchResults.addToFavs);
```

I'm really confused about how to get this to work... somehow it can't read by db table "users" (validated through the console that this is what the table is called) so trying to get it to work but it's not working...

Comment: Where do you call `exports.addToFavs()` from and how do you obtain the first parameter to that function?  My guess would be that you have an asynchronous operation on the DB and you aren't waiting for the results to come back and that's why the `.users` property is undefined  (but that's just a guess without seeing the calling code).

Comment: @jfriend00: it's being called in app.js, in 
app.post('/result', searchResults.addToFavs); 

So basically when it deals with the post request, it calls that specific function.

Comment: What does `app.post()` pass to the callback that you pass it?

Comment: I don't think it passes it anything, is it supposed to?

Comment: The `exports.addToFavs()` function you've shown code for is expecting two arguments passed to it.  If that's the same as `searchResults.addToFavs()`, then that would be your problem.

Comment: It is, but aren't req and res automatically passed into the function because it's just the request and response parameters?

Comment: That's why I asked you what arguments are passed to that function.  The first time, I asked you said nothing was passed in - now you say `req` and `res` are passed in.  That appears to be something you should investigate to make sure you are getting the arguments you want.

Comment: If the size and brandToFind are post parameters, you better use req.body instead of req.query

Comment: Also, I don't know what req.db is. Since you are exporting model using module.exports, when you `require` it, you should be using a variable to store that. Try that variable.users instead of req.db